# How can I make a similar matrix with even column spacing?

Tags: tables, matrices

I'd like to make a similar matrix to the one pictured below, but as you can see, the spacing between the columns is inconsistent due to the length of the words.[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
\[
\bordermatrix{\text{} & \text{all} & \text{dog} & \text{dogs} & \text{eat} & \text{fleas} & \text{go} & \text{has} & \text{heaven} & \text{in} & \text{is} & \text{it} & \text{my} & \text{no} & \text{to} & \text{world} \cr
D_1 & 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \cr   
D_2 &1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0 \cr
D_3 &0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \cr
D_4& 0& 2& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1}
\]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a macro, here `\fxtxt`, which places the overtext entries in a fixed width box of appropriate width, here chosen as 3.5ex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\fxtxt[1]{\makebox[3.5ex]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\bordermatrix{\fxtxt{} & \fxtxt{all} & \fxtxt{dog} & \fxtxt{dogs} & \fxtxt{eat} & \fxtxt{fleas} & \fxtxt{go} & \fxtxt{has} & \fxtxt{heaven} & \fxtxt{in} & \fxtxt{is} & \fxtxt{it} & \fxtxt{my} & \fxtxt{no} & \fxtxt{to} & \fxtxt{world} \cr
D_1 & 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \cr   
D_2 &1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0 \cr
D_3 &0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \cr
D_4& 0& 2& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Follow up to OP query, merely redefining `\fxtxt` to place at 45 degree angle, with narrower width and left alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,rotating}
\newcommand\fxtxt[1]{\rotatebox[origin=left]{45}{\makebox[3ex][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\bordermatrix{\fxtxt{} & \fxtxt{all} & \fxtxt{dog} & \fxtxt{dogs} & \fxtxt{eat} & \fxtxt{fleas} & \fxtxt{go} & \fxtxt{has} & \fxtxt{heaven} & \fxtxt{in} & \fxtxt{is} & \fxtxt{it} & \fxtxt{my} & \fxtxt{no} & \fxtxt{to} & \fxtxt{world} \cr
D_1 & 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \cr   
D_2 &1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0 \cr
D_3 &0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \cr
D_4& 0& 2& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution, but the words "has" and "heaven" are too close together.vvHow would I rotate the top column so the labels are 45 degrees to the horizontal?

Comment: @DemetriP Then increase the `3.5ex` to something more suitable.

Comment: @DemetriP See follow up to answer.

Comment: That is splendid.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `blkarray` and `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
 \newcommand\chd[1]{\makebox[1.33em]{#1}}%

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{blockarray}{*{16}{c}}
  & \chd{all} & \chd{dog} & \chd{dogs} & \chd{eat} & \chd{fleas} & \chd{go} & \chd{has} & \chd{heaven} & \chd{in}%
  & \chd{is} & \chd{it} & \chd{my} & \chd{no} & \chd{to} & \chd{world}\\
  \begin{block}{c(*{15}{c})}
    D_1 & 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
    D_2 &1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
    D_3 &0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
    D_4& 0& 2& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1 \\
  \end{block}
  \end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]