# Matrix with evenly spaced columns

Tags: spacing, amsmath, matrices, columns, mathtools

Similar question: [How can I make a similar matrix with even column spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321099/how-can-i-make-a-similar-matrix-with-even-column-spacing)

---

The following code is simple to write/read/maintain, but looks terrible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix*}  
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is because the negative sign adds extra space between the first and second columns, but not between the second and third.

---

One could naively put a `\phantom{-}` in each column, but this isn't right either.

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        \phantom{-}1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & \phantom{-}1
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

This is because we don't need extra space to the left of each column, but an even amount of space between each column.

---

```
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix*} \\
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & \phantom{-}1
    \end{bmatrix*}  
\end{gather*}
```

[image]

Much better. (The second one, compared to the original above it.)

---

However, in larger matrices, this can easily become hard to read and quite a hassle to maintain.  **Is there some simple way to tell it to put an equal amount of space (say, between the right hand sides) of columns 1&2, 2&3, 3&4, ... ?**

Ideally, I'd like the body of my matrices to contain nothing other than the content:

```
1 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version that uses a new environment `brmatrix`. For the first column the standard `r` column is used, for the other columns we use a new column type `M` which also aligns the content right, but uses a fixed width `\@brcolwidth`. As this is a problem if the content may be wider than the cell and overlap with the other columns, an optional parameter for setting the cell width directly has been added.

A full example with the standard `bmatrix` in the first and the new `brmatrix` in the other cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\hbox to #1\bgroup\hss$}l<{$\egroup}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@brcolwidth{0.67em}
\newenvironment{brmatrix}{%
    \left[%
    \hskip-\arraycolsep
    \new@ifnextchar[\@brarray{\@brarray[\@brcolwidth]}%
}{%
    \endarray
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \right]%
}
\def\@brarray[#1]{\array{r*\c@MaxMatrixCols {M{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{brmatrix}
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1
    \end{brmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{brmatrix}
        -1 &  0 &  0 \\
         0 & -1 &  0 \\
         0 &  0 & -1
    \end{brmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{brmatrix}[2em]
        123 &   0 & 0 \\
          0 & -12 & 0 \\
          0 &   0 & 12345
    \end{brmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was already something like this out there in a standard package.  Ideally `\@brcolwidth` would be automatically determined by scanning the contents of the matrix.

Comment: @TravisBemrose: That's exactly what I show in my example - an automated way of calculating the widest elements in columns 2+.

Comment: @siracusa: Is there a way to rewrite the code to include an optional vertical line (as in an augmented matrix) so that the cell widths can till be altered but a vertical line can be inserted directly between two columns?

Comment: @MarkTwain: The line `\def\@brarray...` defines the column format for the array, i.e. one `r` column and many `M` columns. You could rewrite it with a `|` added where you want the vertical line, I guess. But then you get the line at the same position for all matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach is the same as [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321099/how-can-i-make-a-similar-matrix-with-even-column-spacing), namely using `\makebox`, except that I automated as much as possible.

The main drawback with `mymatrix` is that you have to specify the number of columns.  Note, the minimum spacing is still `2\arraycolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\settowidth{\mycolwidth}{$-1$}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\makebox[\mycolwidth][r]{$#1$}}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\mybox}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newenvironment{mymatrix}[1]% #1 = total number of columns
{\count1=#1\relax
  \advance\count1 by -1
  \left[\array{@{}r*{\number\count1}R@{}}}%
{\endarray\right]}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \begin{mymatrix}{3}
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1
    \end{mymatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was going to delete this after @siracusa solution (so \c@MaxMatrixCols gives the number of columns), but decided that the stylistic contrasts might prove informative.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an automated version called `BMatrix` that takes an optional argument for alignment, adjusting all but the first column of the `BMatrix` environment to have a width equal to the maximum of the entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,collcell,eqparbox}

\newcounter{BMatrix}

\newlength{\maxwd}
\newcommand{\setmaxwd}[1]{%
  \eqmakebox[BM-\theBMatrix][\BMalign]{$#1$}%
}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\newenvironment{BMatrix}[1][c]{
  \def\BMalign{#1}
  \stepcounter{BMatrix}
  \left[\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \MH_let:NwN \@ifnextchar \MH_nospace_ifnextchar:Nnn
  \array{ #1 *{\numexpr\c@MaxMatrixCols-1} {>{\collectcell\setmaxwd}#1<{\endcollectcell}}}
  }{
  \endarray \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \right]
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \texttt{bmatrix*[c]} \\
  \begin{bmatrix*}[c]
    1 &  0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 &  0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix*}
  \qquad
  \begin{bmatrix*}[c]
    123 &   0 &     0 \\
      0 & -12 &     0 \\
      0 &   0 & 12345
  \end{bmatrix*} \\
  \texttt{BMatrix[c]} \\
  \begin{BMatrix}[c]
    1 &  0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 &  0 & 1
  \end{BMatrix}
  \qquad
  \begin{BMatrix}[c]
    123 &   0 &     0 \\
      0 & -12 &     0 \\
      0 &   0 & 12345
  \end{BMatrix} \\
  \texttt{bmatrix*[r]} \\
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    1 &  0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 &  0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix*}
  \qquad
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    123 &   0 &     0 \\
      0 & -12 &     0 \\
      0 &   0 & 12345
  \end{bmatrix*} \\
  \texttt{BMatrix[r]} \\
  \begin{BMatrix}[r]
    1 &  0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 &  0 & 1
  \end{BMatrix}
  \qquad
  \begin{BMatrix}[r]
    123 &   0 &     0 \\
      0 & -12 &     0 \\
      0 &   0 & 12345
  \end{BMatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Each entry in columns 2 and higher are set inside an `\eqmakebox` with a per-`BMatrix` unique tag. The [`eqparbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) then ensures the width of these entries are the same, together with an appropriate alignment specifier. Width calculations uses the `.aux` file and there may require multiple compilations (at first). The first column is left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\widest}{\ensuremath{-1}}
\newcommand{\newWidth}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\widest}]{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 &\newWidth{-1}& 0 \\
        0 &  0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that all this is doing is putting a box around the `(2,2)` entry where you've put `\newWidth`.  When I put `0 & 0 & 1` in the bottom row, the right column no longer has the intended spacing.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` has a key `columns-width=auto` which imposes an equal width for all the columns of the matrix (and a key `r` for a alignment on the right).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[r,columns-width=auto,right-margin]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]